# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE' SQL

Tags: sql

У меня в запросе есть условие для одного столбца чтобы данные начинались на П или на Н, почему выходит ошибка Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LIKE'??

```
select planzp.unplanzp, planzp.ceh, planzp.kzajnpp, planzp.kmat, planzp.undoc, planzp.ntechpr, kum.edi, kum.edi2, kum.kssm, kumk.bs, planzp.kprt, planzp.kol, planzp.npp, planzp.summa, planzp.rcentr 
from planzp 
left join kumk on (planzp.kmat = kumk.kmat) and (planzp.kzajnpp = kumk.kzaj) and (planzp.ceh = kumk.ceh) and (planzp.kprt = kumk.kprt)
left join kum on kum.unkum = kumk.unkum 
where planzp.ceh not IN (102, 105, 107, 108, 10807, 10707, 10210, 10230, 10519, 10731, 10730, 10504, 10201, 10733, 10501, 10215) and kzajnpp not in ('СН') and planzp.kmat IN (LIKE 'П%' or LIKE 'Н%') and planzp.kol > 0 and kum.kssm not IN ('МС02')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно работать с полем, где нужен выборе через `LIKE`, будет так:

```
and (planzp.kmat LIKE 'П%' or planzp.kmat LIKE 'Н%')
```

А `IN` принимает список простых значений (int или string), перечисленных через разделитель, куда  `LIKE 'П%' or LIKE 'Н%'` явно не вписывается

https://oracleplsql.ru/in-mysql.html

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду знать)